# Does passing multiple files to C/C++ compiler allows for interprocedural optimization?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Let's say I have `foo.cpp` with following content

```
int foo() {
  return 123;
}
```

and `main.cpp` in which I use `foo`:

```
int main() {
  int r = foo();
  return r;
}
```

I can compile both source files into object code and then link them using link-time optimizations to make `foo()` call inlined into `main()`.

But can I achieve the same effect by listing both files in compiler command line, like `c++ foo.cpp main.cpp`? Or is it just boils down to

```
foreach(file in files)
  UsualCompilingRoutinesForSingleFile(file)
```

?

If yes, why compiler isn't allowed to concatenate all files passed in into a single one to achieve sort of LTO?

Comment: The compiler is required to produce results as if the files were compiled separately.   However, there is nothing in the standard that prevents interprocedural optimisation, as long as observable effects don't change (e.g. the output is the same) - execution time or memory usage is not considered an observable effect in this sense.   Practically few toolchains do such optimisations and of those that do, most do it after the compilation phase (e.g. while linking, when information is available about all the compilation units).

Comment: At least for GCC, they are compiled as individual translation units, but you can use `-flto` for link-time optimizations. This makes use of internal representations stored in special sections of the object files, which I think allows the compiler to inline stuff from other translation units.

Comment: @Peter can you please elaborate why `The compiler is required to produce results as if the files were compiled separately`? Where does this requirement come from?

Comment: @arrowd -  From every C++ standard.  For example, the 1998 C++ standard, Section 2, para 2, says "The separate translation units of a program communicate (3.5) by (for example) calls to functions whose identifiers have external linkage, manipulation of objects whose identifiers have external linkage, or manipulation of data files. Translation units can be separately translated and then later linked to produce an executable program.".    A "translation unit" is the formal description in the standard of what you're calling a "source file".

Comment: @Peter Okay, I get it. But theoretically, can we compile 2 TUs to some intermediate representation and then perform a link + LTO on this level, without going to object level?

Comment: This is called "unity build". You may benefit from `-fwhole-program` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If yes, why compiler isn't allowed to concatenate all files passed in into a single one to achieve sort of LTO?

The compiler is allowed and able to "see" all files at the "same time" to perform LTO.
But that is indeed not the same as having a single source file.

From the gcc docs ( only as an example, other compilers support similar technology ):

> LTO mode, in which the whole program is read into the compiler at link-time and optimized in a similar way as if it were a single source-level compilation unit.

As you can see, the result will be the same as it would be if you present all files at once to the compiler, but without having trouble from ordering all the included headers / sources in the "correct" order.

For more information from gcc for link time related optimization levels & methods:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO-Overview.html

Answer (score 2):

Concatenating the files is not the same, due to local/static objects. You can have conflicts (think unnamed namespaces). For instance the first file uses a local function `foo` that looks up in a static map something, and then the second file has another local function `foo` that looks up in a hash map (for whatever reason, and yes I agree that it's also a bad design).

If you compile both files together, concatenating them, then you break encapsulation from translation units and you get multiple definitions of the same files.

In your example, the compiler compiles both files separated and the links the together, it's not LTO, which is something else (not generating just object files, but also a kind of AST that can be merged with others, and then optimized).

Comment: There are compilers that can read multiple modules and compile them together, taking advantage of the extra information but honoring the linkage rules.

Comment: There are compiler that do so, probably yes. Traditional compilers though create one object file for each input file.